# getting wrong ELF class warning while trying ruby script to SSH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to ssh to one of the linux servers and then run some commands. Below is the ruby script.
    require 'socket'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ssh'

```
@hostname = "hostname"
@username = "user"
@password = "pass"
@cmd = "ls -alt"

 begin
        ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
        res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
        ssh.close
        puts res    
  rescue
        puts "Unable to connect to #{@hostname} using #{@username}/#{@password}"
  end
```

It gives me the correct output but before giving the output it prints the following warning message:

```
ruby ssh.rb
Nov 5, 2014 3:21:02 PM jnr.netdb.NativeServicesDB load
WARNING: Failed to load native services db
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /lib/libc.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.loadNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:87)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:70)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.findSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:59)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:125)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:63)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:43)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:228)
    at jnr.ffi.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:123)
    at jnr.ffi.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:80)
    at jnr.netdb.NativeServicesDB.load(NativeServicesDB.java:81)
    at jnr.netdb.Service$ServicesDBSingletonHolder.load(Service.java:122)
    at jnr.netdb.Service$ServicesDBSingletonHolder.<clinit>(Service.java:118)
```

I did some research and found this https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7183 but did not understand the solution. Can somebody please guide me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: This problem arises when your trying to load a 32-bit library into a 64-bit process. Make sure the version of JRuby your running is 64bit or the library it is trying to access was compiled for a 64bit operating system. `ruby -v` should output the version, for example a 64bit version will look like `ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Yes, it is using 64-bit JRuby. `ruby -v
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_21-b06 [linux-amd64]`

Comment: That looks fine to me, looks like java is looking in the wrong place for libraries. Personally i haven't touched JRuby before, I hope someone else can help out.

Comment: I added the workaround suggested in `https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7183` to my JRUBY_OPTS and it worked.